# Float is converting my values

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

I have a method that tests a value is within the range allowed on fields. If it is outside the range returns null and if inside returns the value.

```
internal float? ExtractMoneyInRangeAndPrecision(string fieldValue, string fieldName, float min, float max, int scale, int lineNumber)
    {          
        float returnValue;

        //Check whether valid float if
        if (float.TryParse(fieldValue, out returnValue))
        {
            //Check whether in range
            if (returnValue >= min && returnValue <= max)
            {
                int decPosition = 0;
                decPosition = fieldValue.IndexOf('.');

                if (
                    (decPosition == -1) ||
                    ((decPosition != -1) && (fieldValue.Substring(decPosition, fieldValue.Length - decPosition).Length -1 <= scale))
                    )
                {
                    return returnValue;
                }
            }
        }            

        return null;
    }
```

Here is my unit test:

```
[TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("ImporterEngine.dll")]
    public void ExtractMoneyInRangeAndPrecisionTest_OutsideRange()
    {
        MockSyntaxValidator target = new MockSyntaxValidator("", 0);
        string fieldValue = "1000000";
        string fieldName = "";
        float min = 1;
        float max = 999999.99f;
        int scale = 2;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        float? Int16RangeReturned;

        Int16RangeReturned = target.ExtractMoneyInRangeAndPrecision(fieldValue, fieldName, min, max, scale, lineNumber);

        Assert.IsNull(Int16RangeReturned);
    }
```

As you can see the max is 999999.99 but when the method takes it in it changes it to 1,000,000

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

In short, because of the way floating-point numbers represent real numbers, the number you assign to a float is not always the number you get back out. The value you specify is converted to the nearest value that can be represented in scientific notation with a magnitude determined by a base of 2.

In the case of 999999.99, the nearest number that can be represented as a float with the same number of sig figs is 7.6293945 * 2<sup>17</sup> = 999999.99504, which when rounded to the same sig figs is 1,000,000.00. This may not be the EXACT case, but error like this is inherent in the use of floats.

Do not use floating-point types in situations where the accuracy of the number at a given level of precision is required. Instead, use the decimal type, which will retain the precision of values entered.

Comment: Your nearest number is wrong. The two closest numbers are 999999.9375 and 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point types (as defined in C#) are approximate. For precision you should *always* use `decimal`.

From MSDN:

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. **Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.** The approximate range and precision for the decimal type are shown in the following table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

There seems to be some dispute about what qualifies as a floating-point type in C#. While `decimal` does qualify as a floating-point type by actual definition, it is not defined as such according to the MSDN specification.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx

Comment: I know, this isn't my design, I just want to know why it isn't working?

Comment: @user1016253: `float` is always approximated, because of its representation. Check SO and you'll find many questions and answers about this

Comment: @user1016253: look, as example, at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372670/why-is-the-data-stored-in-a-float-datatype-considered-to-be-an-approximate-value)

Comment: Because `float` and `double` are not designed for precision. They're designed for approximate values.

Comment: `decimal` is also a floating-point type. Float and double were designed for speed. `decimal` was designed to be a better match for our real-world use of numbers.

Comment: `decimal` is absolutely **NOT** a floating point type. See my edited answer.

Comment: @James, it absolutely IS a floating point type: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/decimal.html

Comment: Sorry, James, but you're wrong. `decimal` is a floating-point type that uses 10 as its radix. See, for example, this article by Jon Skeet: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx. Change your answer to '**binary** floating-point is approximate for decimal arithmetic' and I'll remove my down-vote.

Comment: I posted the specification for decimal directly from MSDN. See the bolded text.

Comment: MSDN documentation is not infallible. Look at the facts. The idea that floating-point _math_ is approximate is a damaging myth. 99% of the misunderstandings come from people forgetting (or not knowing) that the initial conversion from the human (decimal) form to floating-point may not be exact.

Comment: Let me put it this way: the problem here is not floating-point. The problem is binary vs. decimal. Try working with `1/3` or `2^-29` as a decimal. You'll get round-off error there, too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but we're talking about two different things. You're talking about a mathematical concept and I'm talking about C#. In the scope of C# `decimal` is advised where precision is needed. Obviously `decimal` types have limitations too as they're not infinite, but in general they provide enough precision to represent a number accurately.

Comment: My problem with your answer is that it causes confusion by propagating a common misconception which is also present in the MSDN documentation you rely on: that `decimal` is more precise because it is not a floating-point type. The MSDN docs for System.Decimal correctly say it _is_ a floating-point type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx. I believe the re-wording I suggested above removes the misconception without changing the essence of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not every string of digits can be converted to a float. Without checking, I would say that 999999.99 is one such number. A decimal would solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The float type doesn't have enough precision to do what you want to do. I would recommend using the `decimal` type. Floats can be accurate to 7 decimal digits at most, and you're using 8 here. Decimal can have up to 28 digits, which is more than enough for any amount. Moreover, unlike `float`, the value the compiler uses and the value you write will always be the same.

Here's the long explanation:

Floats (single-precision floating-point numbers) are stored as an integer times a power of two, where the integer is in a certain range (between `2^23` and `2^24`).

When you write a decimal number in your code, the compiler interprets this as the number in this form that is closest to the number you wrote. Sometimes the match is exact (`99999.75`). In other cases, your number needs to be rounded to the closest floating-point number. This is what happened here:

```
99999.99 = 2^19 * 1.907348613739013671875
         = 2^19 * 2^-23 * (2^23 * 1.907348613739013671875)
         = 2^-4 * 15999999.84
```

The closest integer to `15999999.84` is `16000000`, so the rounded value is

```
(float)99999.99 = 2^-4 * 16000000 
                = 1000000
```

The big advantage of the `decimal` type is that is represented as a 96 bit integer times a power of 10, so decimal numbers with up to 28 digits can be represented exactly, without any rounding. What you see is what you get.

The biggest disadvantage of `decimal` is that it is significantly slower, but in a situation like this where you're converting strings to numbers, this is not a factor.